Which alloy forms the thinnest sulfide surface passivation layer?
Metal sulfides seem to often form thick layers on alloy surfaces exposed to molten $\ce{S}$. Are there alloy surfaces capable of passivation with $\ce{S}$ before the layer thickness reaches $\pu{1 nm}$, preferably just single atom thickness? Both the bulk and the surface of the alloy must consist of metallic and/or semi-metallic elements only (excepting $\ce{S}$, of course). The higher the temperature of molten $\ce{S}$, where that kind of passivation can happen, the better. It doesn't need to be a commercially available alloy, since I only need a small amount for experimentation.
If you have no experimental data, theoretical reasons that:

Inhibit the diffusion of sulfur atoms deeper below the surface (assuming the alloy has no grain boundaries is OK).
Make the surface sulfide to stick to the alloy, rather than flake off.

are also welcome.

I note that the object is to form a nanomaterial sulfide surface layer, not to completely protect the metal. Misunderstanding this earned me a downvote followed by my deleting the answer!

https://eprints.nmlindia.org/3412/1/117-136.PDF

Would you also consider other deposition techniques such as CVD, or you are strictly interested in using molten sulfur in bulk? Are there any extra requirements for the metal alloy, or virtually any would do?

@andselisk The process of immersing into molten sulfur has to maintain the layer thinness. It seems to be unlikely that other deposition techniques as a pre-treatment would make a difference. The extra requirements are just metallic conductivity of the alloy bulk and, as already mentioned, the absence of other surface modifiers. No more requirements.

Then CVD or ALD should give you much better thickness control and less diffusion. I still don't quite get why use molten sulfur at all.

@andselisk The molten sulfur is essential, because I am going to need 1. A thin layer robust against both heat and excess sulfur simultaneously. 2. the experiments become much simpler if sulfur can be added just as a bulk liquid.

So, you are asking first and foremost about the metallic alloy that would form as few atomic layers of sulfur/sulfide as possible by simply dipping it into molten sulfur without any chemical modification of the surface (i.e. no anchoring groups), and this sulfide film should be both mechanically and thermally stable?

@andselisk Exactly. Dipping without the presence of air, since oxygen might react before sulfur. Alternatively cleaving below the surface of the molten sulfur.

I see, thank you. Galvanic deposition is out of the question's scope, too, I presume. Tough call.

Is the point in creation of the sulfide lair or in corrosion resistance?

@permeakra The layer is important. However, the layer must not separate easily from the metal. That's why "passivation" correctly describes what is needed.

Effectively, corrosion resistance in hot excess sulfur is the thing that should happen. No need for protectiveness against other corrosive substances.

@PaulKolk I... doubt a protective sulfide layer in such conditions is a possibility. However, alloys with high kinetic resistance to corrosion are very much a thing, see the pdf I linked in the second comment.

@permeakra The pdf briefly mentions chromium's passivation. That may refer to either sulfur or oxygen film.  How thick is this?" Also, it mentions chromium-aluminium steel. Why not chromium-boron alloy? Furthermore, if even commercially viable alloys can stand sulfur above 977 kelvin, why not expect a thinner film to form just above sulfur's melting point 388 kelvin ?

Before the bounty expires, someone can answer "pure chromium is the best we have" and wins 500 reputation immediately :)
